# How to get the number of active events happening in a week given start and end date (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql

This is the current table I have.

```
ID      Start_Date          End_Date
6446    2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-04-01 00:00:00
6848    2018-05-01 00:00:00 2018-05-31 00:00:00
3269    2016-11-09 00:00:00 2016-11-21 00:00:00
7900    2018-11-07 00:00:00 2018-11-30 00:00:00
4006    2017-04-06 00:00:00 2017-04-30 00:00:00
```

Is there a way to get the number of active events per week? Some events might run past a few weeks. Event ID is distinct and can be used to count.

Please help and happy to furnish more info if required.

EDIT 1: The dataset I want is

2019 week 1 - 60 active events
2019 week 2 - 109 active events

I know about WEEK(datetime), however that does not capture the event being active for subsequent weeks.

The issue is that I don't capture the number of active events after the week they are started.

EDIT 2: Week would be defined as the integer returned using the week() function in mysql on a date object. My data is only for 2019.

Comment: you can use week() function wich return week number in the year. Then test just little bit the year and you can work with it.

Comment: Can you share the expected resultset

Comment: How do you define "week 1"? Week containing 1st January? First four days? Does week start on Sunday? Monday?

Comment: @SalmanA Hey I just realised I didn't reply you. "Week 1" would refer to the actual dates of it, extracted using mysql EXTRACT function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use count() function in MySQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE Start > 'start-date' AND End < 'end-date'
```

Comment: Yes, this gives me the count of events active in a specific week. Is it possible to be done for every week in 2019?

Comment: To archieve that i would recommend you to use a programming language such as PHP, Java or whatever. There you can set a counter which increases automatically and you can format the output to your expections.

Comment: I want to bring it to production though. I want my users to be able to refresh the report in excel. If I use a scripting Lang, does it mean my users need to be able to run the script at least?

Comment: If they want the latest state of course they need. If you just run the script from the console or whatever you need to do it as well to get the latest state. It it should happen automatically, maybe you search for something like schedule tasks, so every day or week at 2:30 p.m. your old file would be replaced by a new one

Comment: Hey Max, thanks for your feedback and your answer. I get where you're coming from but this report is going out to complete noobs (lol) so it would be abit difficult to ask them to run the script or something. The next best thing I can consider is to run a script using python (or something) to run the query, put it into excel and upload it into google drive. 
That might work. Haha, thank you Max!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to below query

```
SELECT 
       IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(Start_Date, '%Y WEEK %U'), 0) AS STARTDate, 
       IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(End_Date, '%Y WEEK %U'), 0) AS ENDDate,
       IFNULL(COUNT(ID),0) AS total,
       group_concat(ID)
FROM `event` 
where Start_Date < End_Date
Group by STARTDate;
```

Comment: Hey, that looks kinda useful. I will try that out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, but encountered a new problem.

Building upon Kranti's code, the answer is as follows.

```
SELECT 
   EXTRACT(WEEK FROM starting_date) AS STARTDate, 
   EXTRACT(WEEK FROM ending_date) AS ENDDate,
   discount_type,
   COUNT(ID) AS total
   FROM `event` 
   where starting_date < ending_date
   Group by 1,2
```

What this gives me is the number of events that have happened from Week 1 - 3, Week 1-4 etc, so on and so forth.

Afterwards, we do a left join with the weeks of interest, on the condition where the week numbers are in between STARTDate and ENDDate. Due to how a left join works, it will duplicate rows for all the rows that fulfill the specific condition.

We follow up with a groupby and sum, which will give us the number of events that were active, for each week.

Comment: The new problem is when my events span a year. That messes up my EXTRACT (WEEK ...) function. Still investigating.